# Chrome extension using NaCl module(C code) wont accept my messages

Tags: javascript, c, google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

I've been placed on this project where I need to capture a base64 encoded pdf string in the javascript level and then display it. A lot of the code was written before I started and he was already able to send the base64 string to the javascript level and log it to the console. I need to grab the string and store it in a var to decode and then use pdf.js to  display it. Right now I have gone through the nacl messaging guide but it does not seem to work(I just want it to alert "Hello World") to make sure I am getting the variable. Here is some of the code.

vdocs_pdf.c

```
    base64encode(document_buffer, document_used, base64_buf, base64_size);
    captured_base64 = CStrToVar(base64_buf);
    free(base64_buf);
    captured_flag = 1;
    struct PP_Var var = CStrToVar("hello world");
    ppb_messaging_interface->PostMessage(this_instance, var);
    LogVar(captured_base64);
    SendVar(captured_base64);

static struct PP_Var CBufToVar(const char* str, size_t len)
{
  if (ppb_var_interface) {
    return ppb_var_interface->VarFromUtf8(str, len);
  }
  return PP_MakeUndefined();
}

static struct PP_Var CStrToVar(const char* str)
{
  return CBufToVar(str, strlen(str));
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!--
Copyright (c) 2012 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
found in the LICENSE file.
-->
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
  <title>vdocs_pdf</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vdocs_pdf.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-name="vdocs_pdf" data-tools="newlib glibc pnacl linux" data-configs="Debug Release" data-path="{tc}/{config}">
  <h1>vdocs_pdf</h1>
  <h2>Status: <code id="statusField">NO-STATUS</code></h2>
  <p>vdocs_pdf will accept the application/pdf data and pass
     it up to javascript as a base64 encoded string variable.</p>
  <h2>Output:</h2>
  <pre id="log" style="font-weight: bold"></pre>
  <!-- The NaCl plugin will be embedded inside the element with id "listener".
      See common.js.-->
  <div id="listener"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

vdoc_pdf.js

```
// Copyright (c) 2012 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// Once we load, hide the plugin
function moduleDidLoad() {
  common.hideModule();
}

// Called by the common.js module.
function handleMessage(message) {
  common.logMessage(message.data);
}

var listener = document.getElementById('listener');
listener.addEventListener
(
    "message",
  function(message) 
  { 
    alert(message.data); 
  },
  false
);
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and why I can't alert with the "Hello World"?

Here Is the output from my console which clearly means messages are getting passed to the javascript level. It just is not working when I send up the "Hello World" string.

```
V-DOCS PDF 1.0 (JavaScript Console)! 
HandleDocumentLoad(instance(62dde6dd) url_loader(30)) 
document buffer(fed50008) used(0) max(100000) 
document buffer(fed50008) used(1193) max(100000) 
document buffer(fed50008) used(2641) max(100000) 
document buffer(fed50008) used(4089) max(100000) 
document buffer(fed50008) used(5537) max(100000) 
document buffer(fed50008) used(6985) max(100000) 
document buffer(fed50008) used(8433) max(100000) 
document buffer(fed50008) used(9881) max(100000) 
document buffer(fed50008) used(11329) max(100000) 
document buffer(fed50008) used(12777) max(100000) 
document buffer(fea40008) used(1053574) max(1600000) 
base64_size(1475013) 
JVBERi0xLjYNJeLjz9MNCjY4MiAwIG9iag08PC9MaW5lYXJpemVkIDEvTCAxMDUzNTc0L08gNjg4L0UgODMzNDYvTiAyL1QgMTA1MzA5OS9IIFsgNzA1IDM5OV0+Pg1l...
```

The last line being the base64 encoded pdf. Is there anything else that would be of value to help you guys help me fix the problem? I really feel like my changes to the Javascript code are not being taken into affect and have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

The `embed.addEventListener` line looks wrong to me. `embed` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. Make sure you check the JavaScript console for errors. See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console.

Also remember that the embed element isn't available when this script is running; because the script is in the  element, it runs before any element in the body has been created. If you want to access the embed element, you have to wait until  it is created. You can do that in the `moduleDidLoad` function:

```
function moduleDidLoad() {
  common.hideModule();

  // common.naclModule is the embed element...
  common.naclModule.postMessage("foobar");
}
```

The `handleMessage` function above it should already be handling messages from the NaCl module. If you want to alert, try this:

```
function handleMessage(message) {
  alert(message.data);
}
```

Comment: The embed was a mistake but doesn't seem to change anything. I put an alert in the handle message but it does nothing. This may sound like a strange question but do you need to compile the javascript? Changes to my code don't seem to do anything. I always remove and then re-add the extension before I test it as well.

Comment: No, JavaScript doesn't need to be compiled. Have you tried using console.log instead of alert? I know that in some cases alert() is blocked by the browser (in a Chrome App, for example).

Comment: I will try to see if log will work but I have commented out all of the code in all my js files and had it still "work" as before after a remove and reload. Which points to the code not being updated for whatever reason.